# How to disable SSL in CAS client

Tags: java, cas, jasig

I am using CAS client code in https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client.
Following https://github.com/cas-projects/cas-sample-java-webapp tutorial I have this dependency in my pom file:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

And I have used filters in https://github.com/cas-projects/cas-sample-java-webapp/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml for my project.

So far so good. The only problem I got is that this code uses ssl but I don't want to use ssl and my server has not been configured to have ssl.
Is there any way to customize this java cas client code for this purpose?

ps: I need to test my code so I don't have to use ssl for secure communication. Later I will have my server configured for ssl. And the cas server i'm connecting accepts communication with no ssl.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes, The error says I have not configured ssl in my tomcat server. As I said I don't want to have ssl in my server yet. I want to have a connection without ssl for testing purpose.